# Parent class for singleton pattern | setting field to instance of child class

Tags: c#, .net

I’m trying to implement a simple singleton parent class for internal use (I only want to avoid static fields and don’t care about safety).

The reason I want a generic parent class is so I don’t have to worry about boilerplate and can simply inherit from `Simpleton`. I plan on having quite a few of these.

Here’s what I have:

```cs
class Simpleton
{
    static Simpleton instance;
    static Simpleton()
    {
        instance = new Simpleton();
    }
    
    // I know this naming isn’t ideal, but I’m going for brevity and I’m the only one using this codebase
    static Simpleton I { get => instance; }

}
```

This works if I actually want to use an instance of `Simpleton` but I want to create a child class and use it:

```cs
class Settings : Simpleton
{
    public int testSetting = 1;
}

// somewhere else
void Test()
{
    // compiler error since Simpleton does not contain the field `testSetting`
    var num = Settings.I.testSetting;
}
```

I just want to make the `static Simpleton()` function set `instance` to an instance of the child class. I can do this with reflection, but I can’t figure out how to do it such that the compiler *knows* that it is an instance of the child class.

I’m surprisingly stumped on how to make this work, and since my main goal is to have as little boilerplate as possible in the child class, I want to avoid overriding to whatever extent possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make your Singleton a generic, and then derive `Settings` from `Singleton<Settings>`, like this:

```
var t = Settings.Instance.testSetting;

Console.WriteLine(t);

class Singleton<T> where T: new()
{ 
    public static T Instance = new T();
}

class Settings : Singleton<Settings>
{
    public int testSetting = 1;
}
```

Comment: Are Simpleton and Singleton the same thing?

Comment: A "Singleton" is a type which only has one instance.  A "Simpleton" is a person with very low intelligence, and has no common usage in computer programming.

Comment: Ah, right, completely forgot this was possible! Cheers mate